# $S_3\oplus S_3$ has an element of order $4,6,9$ or $18$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, least-common-multiple

$S_3\oplus S_3$ has an element of order $4,6,9$ or $18$. $\oplus$ is the direct sum.

Its order is $36$ so by sylow theorem it has subgroups of order $4$ and $9$. Also order of a permutation is the lcm of the order of disjoint cycles. But when I consider elements of $S_3\oplus S_3$ the cycles might not be disjoint eg. $(12)(123)$. It says the answer is 6 but I'm not convinced because of this reason.

Comment: I guess $\oplus$ is supposed to be the direct product?

Comment: @0x539 Or possibly direct sum. Not that it makes much difference in this case.

Comment: The first and second $S_3$ have nothing to do with each other. To prevent confusion, it could probably help to see $S_3 \oplus S_3$ as a subgroup of $S_6$, where the first $S_3$ is $S(\{1,2,3\})$ and the second is $S(\{4,5,6\})$.

Comment: @TastyRomeo Yeah that was the source of the confusion, ty.

Answer (score 2):

That $\oplus$ symbol? It's the direct sum; anything from one piece commutes with anything from the other. We can represent the elements as ordered pairs $(a,b)$, with group operation $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = (a\cdot c, b\cdot d)$. It doesn't matter if the cycles aren't disjoint between the two objects - we're not going to multiply across that line anyway.